# How do I assign ref to each element rendered by array mapping and how do I reference them

Tags: reactjs, dom, ref

What I need: I need to assign specific ref to each div, so I can detect the click outside each specific input field, but since the items are rendered by mapping all divs have same reference. For example, when I click the div of item2 it detects that it's the ref so it doesn't trigger the alert.

```
const ref = useRef(null)

const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      alert('clicked')
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true)

    return () => {  
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true)
    }
})


myList = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

myList.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item._id} ref={ref}>
        <input type="text" value={item.value} />
      </div>
    )
}
```

The myList is a representation of my state and are dynamic

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the reference as an array, and for each index assign the related reference.

```
const listRef = useRef([]);

myList.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={item._id} ref={(ref) => (listRef.current[i] = ref)}>
      <input type="text" value={item.value} />
    </div>
  );
});

// Now each array entry contains a reference to `div` element.
// access the reference through index.
listRef.current[i].contains(e.target);
```

Bonus: here is an example of `useOnClickOutside` custom hooks implementation:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function useOnClickOutside(ref, handler) {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = event => {
        // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
        if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
          return;
        }
        handler(event);
      };

      document.addEventListener(`mousedown`, listener);
      document.addEventListener(`touchstart`, listener);

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener(`mousedown`, listener);
        document.removeEventListener(`touchstart`, listener);
      };
    },

    // Add ref and handler to effect dependencies
    // It's worth noting that because passed in handler is a new ...
    // ... function on every render that will cause this effect ...
    // ... callback/cleanup to run every render. It's not a big deal ...
    // ... but to optimize you can wrap handler in useCallback before ...
    // ... passing it into this hook.

    [ref, handler],
  );
}

export default useOnClickOutside;
```